# Getting 401 error despite setting env MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN with python requests module

Tags: python-requests, environment-variables, basic-authentication, bearer-token, mlflow

I am running mlflow inside of the docker container.
mlflow has no default authentication but it has basic authentication by running **mlflow server --app-name basic-auth**

Able to fetch the data when credentials were provided instead of Bearer token default credentials are **user=admin,password=password**
**I am encountering a 401 error(unauthorized) while trying to fetch data using the Python requests module, despite setting the MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN environment variable.**

In the documentation they mentioned:
MLFLOW_TRACKING_USERNAME and MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD - username and password to use with HTTP Basic authentication. To use Basic authentication, you must set both environment variables .

MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN - token to use with HTTP Bearer authentication. Basic authentication takes precedence if set.

reference:https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking/server.html

Steps to Replicate
1.Run MLflow inside a Docker container.
2.exec into the container.
3.export MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN=<random_string>.

I tried the following ways:
import requests

##working with credentials
response = requests.get(r'http://<tracking_uri:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/search', json={"max_results":10}, auth=("admin","password"))

##but not working with **Bearer token**
response = requests.get(r'http://<tracking_uri:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/search', json={"max_results":10}, headers={"Authorization":f"Bearer <random_string>"})
print(response)

##error
You are not authenticated. Please see https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/auth/index.html#authenticating-to-mlflow on how to authenticate.